# Morphia datastore.save() behaviour

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

We hare using morphia 0.109 to insert records, using the following syntax:

```
AdvancedDatastore datastore = MongoDbFactory.getDatastore();
datastore.save(collectionName, pojo);
```

It appears that when the object does not exist yet in mongodb morphia first issues a delete and then an insert request?

Is the only way to get arround this to specifically use the **.insert** and **.update** methods in java instead of **.save**?

[image]

Comment: This is expected behavior for the save operation. Think of it as "no matter what, save the entity the way it is". What you want to do is an update operation, which are bound to specific fields or the whole entity will be replaced (that's by MongoDB, not Morphia). You might want to read [*Updating* in the Morphia docs](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Updating) for details.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - Many thanks for the quick confirmation. Thanks.

Comment: Resurrecting this ancient thread for modern times: is this true of the `save(Iterable)` method? I'm noticing what looks like destructive behavior where a prior insert of one record is getting seemingly obliterated by a subsequent `save` of two records.  I'd expect three, but instead it is as if the first (acknowledged) insert never happened.