# Saving document to a specific collection in a datastore

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have only one entity class which is applicable to all the collections I have. Now, I would like to save some document to a specific collection. Is there a way to do it? As [shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844648/morphia-datastore-save-behaviour), but it's not working with Morphia 2.2 which is something like

```
Datastore datastore = Morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "testdatastore");
datastore.save(collectionName, student);
```

For better understanding, here is an example. I have an entity "Student"

```
import java.util.Date;    
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;    
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvDate;    
import dev.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import dev.morphia.annotations.Id;

@Entity("students")
public class Student{
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Name")
    private String name;

    @CsvDate(value = "dd-MMMM-yy")
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Date")
    private Date date;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "sport")
    private String sport;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "subject")
    private String subject;

//with getters and setters
}
```

Now, I would like to save each students data in a separate collection. A snapshot of how data looks in MongoDbCompass is as follows

[image]

I found a way to do that, but it seems to bypass Morphia.

```
datastore.getDatabase().getCollection(collectionName).insertOne(studentRow.toDocument());
```

The toDocument() method is a custom method to map student object to Document.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is a form of multitenancy which Morphia doesn't currently support.  I have given thought to various approaches to that but haven't settled on any particular approach just yet.